# How can i format a link for pytube?

Tags: python, pytube, dearpygui

im working on a Youtube Downloader with pytube and dearpygui (dpg) right now.

While trying to fuse the GUI with the rest of the Code i ran into Issues with pytube.

Error Code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mitja\Documents\ytdownload\ytdownloadGUI.py", line 25, in downloadbutton
    yt = YouTube(videolink)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mitja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.video_id = extract.video_id(url)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mitja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 133, in video_id
    return regex_search(r"(?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*", url, group=1)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mitja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\helpers.py", line 129, in regex_search
    raise RegexMatchError(caller="regex_search", pattern=pattern)
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*
```

The the parts of the Code that produce the error are:

```py
videolink = ''  
def link(Sender, Data):
    videolink = dpg.get_value(24)
    print(videolink)
```

```py
dpg.add_input_text(label="Video Link", hint="youtube.com/", callback=link)
```

Could it be that the Text that i extract from dpg is in the wrong format for pytube?

I already tried to make it a raw string etc.

I have found nothing on google and here on Stackoverflow too.

Does someone know how to format the link so that pytube can use it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the way your link() function is called is incorrect, you have not referred properly for dgp.get_value()

make sure to keep the s in sender small, and I am assuming you referred to 24 as the size you required,

```
def link(sender, data):
    videolink = dpg.get_value(sender)
    print(videolink)
```

This code will continuously print the videolink, for optimizing for printing only when pressed enter try this:

```
 dpg.add_input_text(label="Video Link", hint="youtube.com/", callback=link, on_enter= True)
```

This would call the function when you pressed enter and would print the text

Similarly, you can trigger it by a button too.